# Using Cobertura Sonar plugin with CXF 2.5.x

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube, cobertura

is it possible to use Cobertura plugin on module that uses CXF 2.5.x. The problem is that when I run Sonar I receive following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot override read-only parameter: classesDirectory in goal: cxf-codegen:wsdl2java
```

The problem is known but has not been fixed:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4002
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-855

I can't change Cobertura plugin to JaCoCo.

Anyone know any workaround? Is it possible to exclude wsdl2java goal when using Sonar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading CXF to 2.5.4/2.6.1 is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can put the wsdl2java goal into a specific profile in your POM. This profile would be activated by default, but you would provide a property to deactivate it.

E.g.:

```
<profile>
  <id>run-wsdl2java</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>!skipWsdl2java</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  ...
</profile>
```

Then, when running Sonar, you could just launch:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -DskipWsdl2java
```